# Applying Factory Pattern Extensively

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I'm developing a game and there are tons of occasions where I need some sort of factory pattern involved.
In an attempt not to create lots of Factory class methods, I used `Supplier<T>` instead. This works great but not if there are required arguments.

It works in this case: `() -> new Spawn(3, 6, "example");`

But sometimes I need to pass other parameters to the factory.
There's the `Consumer` and `BiConsumer` which accept two parameters. But there's no interface for 3, 4, 5...

I came up with an embarassing solution to this problem, but it illustrates what I'm trying to achieve. What other solutions are there?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FactoryExample {

    static class Args {
        Object[] objs;
        Args(Object ...objs) { this.objs = objs; }
        Object[] get() { return objs; }
    }

    static class Thing {
        int a; char b; boolean c;
        Thing(int a, char b, boolean c) {
            this.a = a; this.b = b; this.c = c; }
    }

    static class Number {
        int x;
        Number(int x) { this.x = x; }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<Args, Number> factoryA = arg -> {
            int x = (int) arg.get()[0];
            return new Number(x);   
        };

        Function<Args, Thing> factoryB = arg -> {
            int a = (int) arg.get()[0];
            char b = (char) arg.get()[1];
            boolean c = (boolean) arg.get()[2];
            return new Thing(a, b, c);
        };

        factoryB.apply(new Args(3, 'a', true));
        factoryA.apply(new Args(3));
    }

}
```

**Example: how do I avoid creating a bunch of these factories?**

```
public class InfectionFactory {

    private Integer damage;
    private Integer delay;
    private Integer hits;
    private Integer spikes;
    private Color color;

    public InfectionFactory setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    public InfectionFactory setSpikes(int spikes) {
        this.spikes = spikes;
        return this;
    }

    public InfectionFactory setDamage(int damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
        return this;
    }

    public InfectionFactory setDelay(int delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
        return this;
    }

    public InfectionFactory setHits(int hits) {
        this.hits = hits;
        return this;
    }

    public Infection create(Game game, Living target) {
        Infection infection = new Infection(game, target);

        if (damage  != null) infection.setDamage(damage);
        if (color   != null) infection.setColor(color);
        if (delay   != null) infection.setDelay(delay);
        if (hits    != null) infection.setHits(hits);
        if (spikes  != null) infection.setSpikes(spikes);

        return infection;
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than posting a solution, can you post your real problem in code?

Comment: Sure @jbx ... updating

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple requirements. First of all, to make the `Supplier` take all the arguments you want, you can do something like:

```
public class SpawnFactory implements Supplier<Spawn> {
  //todo: put members for all the arguments you need, make them final so that you don't miss any in the constructor

  public SpawnFactory( ... all the arguments you want ... ) {

  }

  public Spawn get() {
    return new Spawn( ... all the arguments you want ...);
  }
}
```

Since it implements `Supplier`, you can pass them directly instantiated the way you like. Instead of `() -> new Spawn(3, 6, "example")` just do `new SpawnFactory(3, 6, "example");`

The example of your `InfectionFactory` on the other hand is following the builder pattern (you might want to rename it `InfectionBuilder`). Nothing is wrong with this (apart from the fact that it seems a bit redundant since `Infection` is using the same pattern too)

You might want to make it take the `Game` and `Living` as constructor arguments instead, and then your `create()` will not need any arguments. Your last step would be to make the class `implement Supplier<Infection>` and add `Infection get()` which just calls `create()` (unless you want to rename `create()` to `get()`).